# Import profile from firefox to firefox snap

Tags: 20.04, 22.04, firefox, snap

I made a new install of 22:04.2 on another partition. I have all program left on the old partition with Ubuntu 20.04 and want to import my profile from my old firefox on Ubuntu 20:04
Tried to copy home/user/.mozilla/firefox to home/user/snap/firefox, but it does not work.
Is there any solution?

/Cheers

Comment: Use the Firefox export and import functions. Unless your profile is more then book marks. There is also the Firefox sync function.

Answer (score 2):

I find a solution in mozillas help on copying the hole old profiles files. I could take all profile-files from latest firefox-version from 20:04, to the latest firefox-snap on 22:04.2 The problem was that i copied the hole profile-folder with a long file-name containing numbers.

Here is the tutorial I use.

https://support.mozilla.org/sv/kb/recovering-important-data-from-an-old-profile

/Cheers